# what's the purpose of static read only 'Empty' in EventArgs

Tags: c#, oop, events

I'm new to C#, just a question on EventArgs class. We know the definition is :

```
public class EventArgs
{
   public static readonly EventArgs Empty;
   public EventArgs();
}
```

and I guess one of the use is when you don't care about passing custom information

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> TestHappening;

private void MyMethod()
{
    TestHappening( this, EventArgs.Empty );
}
```

but can't we achieve the same goal by using:

```
 TestHappening( this, new EventArgs() );
```

Comment: In the source its `public static readonly EventArgs Empty = new EventArgs();` and this is just a static Empty member to save allocations

Comment: I think it's just better readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's preferable to use `EventArgs.Empty` for two reasons:

1. Checking if arguments are empty is convenient

   ```
   EventArgs newArgs = new EventArgs();
   EventArgs emptyArgs = EventArgs.Empty;
   Console.WriteLine(newArgs == EventArgs.Empty); // false
   Console.WriteLine(emptyArgs == EventArgs.Empty); // true
   ```
2. No extra memory allocation because you essentially use the same class instance.

Answer (score 0):

EventArgs.Empty is just define an instance of EventArgs without data. In C# there is a lot of class with defined property to declare a state or a kind or a value of this class to support who are just approach C#. `string.Empty`, `int.MaxValue`, etc are example for this